# Can a function template be made to do default actions upon an inappropriate type instead of an error?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to create a function like:

```
template < typename Other, typename Func, typename T, typename ...Rest >
void  visit( Other &&other, Func &&visitor )
{
    // Wrap "visitor" and "other" with "std::forward" calls
    visitor( make_object<T>(other) );
    visit<Other, Func, Rest...>( other, visitor );
}
```

The problem is that "Func" may not support all of the types in the list, then the compiler will crap out at the first bad one.  I don't want that; I want it to do some default action instead (for my case, do nothing at all).

```
template < typename Other, typename Func, typename T, typename ...Rest >
void  visit( Other &&other, Func &&visitor )
{
    // Wrap "visitor" and "other" with "std::forward" calls
    if ( Func-can-support-T-either-directly-or-by-converting-it )
        visitor( make_object<T>(other) );
    else
        ;  // might be a throw or a logging instead
    visit<Other, Func, Rest...>( other, visitor );
}
```

I guess that I can make 2 overloaded auxiliary functions, one taking `std::true_type` based on the test for compatibility, and the other `std::false_type`.  But how do I create the test?

(Suggestions for a better title and/or additional tags appreciated.)

Comment: Why do you want a runtime `throw` rather than a compile time error? Doesn't seem too useful.

Comment: [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) is your friend.

Comment: BoPersson, throwing is just an example of a run-time policy for non-matching types.  My code needs the do-nothing policy.  The goal is a framework that avoids compile-time errors when no match is found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with all problems in computing, a simple level of indirection is all you need :)

Here is a simple `apply` function that has a default implementation when things don't work as you wish they did.

```
template <typename Func>
void apply(Func&& f, ...) { std::cout << "default\n"; }

template <typename Func, typename T>
auto apply(Func&& f, T&& t) -> decltype(f(std::forward<T>(t))) {
    return f(std::forward<T>(t));
}
```

We can exercise it easily enough:

```
struct Foo {};
struct Bar {};

struct F {
    void operator()(Foo) { std::cout << "Foo\n"; }
    void operator()(Bar) { std::cout << "Bar\n"; }
};

int main() {
    F f;
    Foo foo;
    Bar bar;
    int i;
    apply(f, foo);
    apply(f, bar);
    apply(f, i);
}
```

Ideone gives [the following output](http://ideone.com/DkXw0):

```
Foo
Bar
default
```

as expected.